# при добавлении цифр в конец url страница доступна

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Сайт написан на WordPress. Файл .htaccess стандартный. Находясь на странице услуг (http:/сайт/strizhka-volos/), при добавлении **цифр** в конец url страница доступна. Хотелось бы увидеть 404 ошибку или 301 редирект. Подскажите какое может быть решение?

Comment: Дмитрий, Вы решили проблему? Я не вижу проблемы...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> при добавлении цифр в конец url страница доступна. Хотелось бы увидеть 404 ошибку или 301 редирект. Подскажите какое может быть решение?

Если "в конец" - это после слеша (`http://сайт/strizhka-volos/`**`123`**), то это пагинация. Пытаясь от неё избавиться можно всё поломать.

Если ВДРУГ пагинация нигде не используется (что маловероятно), то можно сделать редирект.
Кроме того во избежание дублей на таких страницах должен быть каноникал (canonical) на основную. Тут у ВП есть нюансы.
В любом случае и каноникалом и редиректом (в данном случае) можно управлять с пом СЕО-плагинов.

Comment: 'nopaging' => true - не решит этот вопрос?
Хотя да, тут же вряд ли используется query, не подумал - это же обычные страницы

Comment: @eugene_v Какой тип контента и даже что за страницы - не столь важно. Эта багофича ВП - пагинация по цифрам в конце урла. nopaging просто не будет бить архивные страницы на подстраницы, но ни 301 ни 404 не даст. Возможно только каноникал пропишет (эт надо проверять, я не знаю точно). Но не везде ж. Так что тут нужны СЕО плаги и иногда  даже редиректы в хтацессе, если в ПСах появились левые урлы, а условия сайта не позволяют их исправить СЕО-плагами.

Answer (score 0):

добавьте это в functions.php

```
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
```